# Why must closures as optional stored properties be initialized?

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

In Swift, I can declare a stored property of any type like so:

```
class MyClass {
  let foo : AnyObject
}
```

Swift will then complain that `MyClass` has no initializers. I have a few options here:

```
// 1. Assign a default value to `foo`, like so:

class MyClass {
  let foo : AnyObject = "bar"
}

// 2. Create an initializer, 
//    which assigns a default value to `foo` before returning.

class MyClass {
  let foo : AnyObject

  init() {
     foo = "bar"
  }
}

 // 3. Make `foo` into an optional, 
 //    which changes its type, but removes the 
 //    requirement for a default value. 

class MyClass {
  let foo : AnyObject?
}
```

However, if I make `foo` into a closure, Option 3 no longer works. For example, consider this:

```
class MyClass {
  let foo : ((bar : AnyObject)-> Void)
}
```

This code sample causes the compiler to complain:

> `MyClass` has no initializers. 
>   - The Swift 2.1 Compiler

That's reasonable, so let's try the different solutions:

```
class MyClass {
  let foo : ((bar : AnyObject)-> Void) = {() -> Void in }
}
```

This works, because we've assigned a default value. This probably isn't what I want, though. We can change our default value to `nil`, but only if we make the property into an Optional. Let's try that:

```
class MyClass {
  let foo : ((bar : AnyObject)-> Void)? = nil
}
```

This works, but what if we want to remove the `= nil` part?

```
class MyClass {
  let foo : ((bar : AnyObject)-> Void)?
}
```

The compiler throws the same error as before! Why? Shouldn't making my property Optional be enough, even without the default value?

Comment: I had a false premise while writing this question, and didn't realize that in my initial example, case 3, I *also* had to assign nil to the optional as the default value. Leaving this up for posterity, but this question is based on a false premise. I'll be answering it myself as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: that's because your property is `let` not `var`, you use let but you didn't assign any value, `var foo : ((bar : AnyObject)-> Void)?` will be ok